# how to distinguish function type with SFINAE

Tags: c++, sfinae

I'm reading book *C++ Templates*. It mentions SFINAE(substitution failure is not an error) principal can be used to detect function type. 
Code example:

```
template <typename T>
class IsFunctionT {
private:
   typedef char One;
   typedef struct { char a[2]; } Two;
   template<typename U> static One test(...);
   template<typename U> static Two test(U (*)[1]); // This test overloading I cannot understand 
public:
   enum { Yes = sizeof(IsFunctionT<T>::test<T>(0) == 1};
   enum { No = !Yes };
};
```

I understand its intent is to find functions which cannot be categorized as arrays, but how does it work with `U (*)[1]`. I have never seen this before.

Comment: You cannot have array of functions, which is where the substitution failure will happen.

Comment: I don't think this template can work as intended. For examle, references cannot be categorized as arrays too, so reference type will be considered as function type by this template.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, SFINAE works by substituting a type and not giving a hard failure if the expression is ill-formed. For example you cannot have an array of functions, so if `U` is a function, the substitution will fail and that overload will be discarded. Now as a comment pointed out, the code you posted alone does not cover all cases. You need additional specializations, i.e:

```
template<typename T>
class IsFunctionT<T&> {
  public:
    enum { Yes = 0 };
    enum { No = !Yes };
};

template<>
class IsFunctionT<void> {
  public:
    enum { Yes = 0 };
    enum { No = !Yes };
};

template<>
class IsFunctionT<void const> {
  public:
    enum { Yes = 0 };
    enum { No = !Yes };
};
```

Which I pulled from the freely available [source code from the book](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/types/typet.hpp.html).

Comment: Rvalue reference is still not covered. And nor are `volatile void` and `const volatile void`.

Comment: Contact the author of the book, not me.

Answer (score -1):

The U(*)[1] is an unnamed pointer to an array of 1 element. And the 0 is either treated as an int or a null pointer to an U (*)[1];

The sizeof is testing the function return type, the actual result of the test function isn't used as test() is never actually called, only its return type tested.

Comment: I believe the question was why it works, not only about pointer.